# Problem in remove interaction after draw end in openlayers-3

Tags: openlayers, draw-interaction

I'm using [**OpenLayers-3.8.2**](http://openlayers.org). I have a [`draw Ineraction`](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.8.2/apidoc/ol.interaction.Draw.html) as follow:

```
function drawEnd(){
   map.removeInteraction(drawIneraction).
}
var drawInteraction = new ol.interaction.Draw({
   source: mysource,
   type: 'LineString'
});
drawInteraction.on('drawend', drawEnd);
map.addInteraction(drawInteraction);
```

I want to user draw just one feature. This Code work, but when user draw a feature, map zoom in 2 level.

**How can I prevent zooming in**?

Answer (score 4):

The proper way to handle this is something like:

```
// Find the double click interaction that is on the map.
var dblclickzoom;
map.getInteractions().forEach(function (interaction) {
   if (interaction instanceof ol.interaction.DoubleClickZoom) {
       dblclickzoom=interaction;
   }
});

// Remove the interaction from the map.
if (dblclickzoom) { map.removeInteraction(dblclickzoom); }

/* Add your draw interaction here */
var drawinteraction=new ol.interaction.Draw(...);

// I like to stick the listener on the source's change event rather than
// the interaction's drawend, but I think either should work...
drawinteraction.on('drawend', function () {
   map.removeInteraction(drawinteraction);
   // Do this in a timeout so it doesn't get triggered by the potential
   // double click that caused the drawing to end.
   if (dblclickzoom) {
       setTimeout(function () {
          map.addInteraction(dblclickzoom);
       });
   }
});
// Start the draw interaction...
map.addInteraction(drawinteraction);
```

Answer (score 3):

[Try the stopClick option](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_interaction_Draw.html#~Options)

```
var drawInteraction = new ol.interaction.Draw({
   source: mysource,
   type: 'LineString',
   stopClick: true
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can listen for the `dblclick` event and then simply `return false;` to disable the zoom; However you need to set a condition for it so it will disable the zoom only when the user is drawing.

```
map.on( "dblclick", function (e) {
   if ( drawingMode ) {
       return false;
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

by setting this before draw you can disable the zoom on double click,

```
ol.interaction.defaults({
    doubleClickZoom :false
})
```

after removing the draw interaction set back the double click zoom to true